# How to store video on the windows form app

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to store some videos on my Windows Form App. I can code the app to play from the file path but I was wondering if there's a way to store the videos on the app as this app is intended to be circulated and I want the whole thing to be integrated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could add the video file as an embedded resource? In your resources tab in the project, you should be able to select and change resources and their settings.

Comment: Does that work for video files too? I was able to add it to the embedded resource and change its property to "Embedded Resource" but I'm struggling to build a code to play the file on my media control. I'm fairly new at this and can use all the help! Thanks in advance

Comment: @Karan You mentioned earlier that you could load the video. Instead of referencing a path to the video (ex: `C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\video.mov`), use: `Properties.Resources.<whatever your video resource name is>`.

Answer (score 0):

What about saving a Video File using Fileupload Conntrol in C#.net? I give only proposal.

```
try
        {
            UploadVideo obj = new UploadVideo();
            string filename = fuUploadVideo.FileName;
            string path = Server.MapPath("Uploads4");
            string strFinalFileName = Path.GetFileName(fuUploadVideo.FileName);
            long FileLength = fuUploadVideo.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            long uploadchunklimit;
            int SizeLimit = (int)FileLength;
            if (FileLength <= 1024)
            {
                uploadchunklimit = 1;
                SizeLimit = (int)FileLength;
            }
            else if (FileLength > 1024)
            {
                uploadchunklimit = FileLength / 1024;
                SizeLimit = 10;
            }
            else if (FileLength <= 10240 && FileLength > 1024)
            {
                uploadchunklimit = FileLength / 1024;
            }
            else
            {
                uploadchunklimit = FileLength / 1024;
            }

            long lngSize = (long)SizeLimit;
            lngSize = 1024 * 1024;
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fuUploadVideo.PostedFile.FileName);

            fuUploadVideo.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads4\\" + filename));
            path = "Uploads4\\" + filename;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into electronicmedia(Video_Name,url) values(@Video,'" + path + "')", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Video", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            lblinfo.Text = " uploaded successfully ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **SQL Server Compact** in your project. It will be embedded in your Windows Forms app and you can keep files in binary columns.

There are other possibilities to consider also:

- Keep the videos in regular folder in a sub-folder of your program (or in user's folder)
- You could use embedded resources (like mentioned in previous answers)
- Use **Compound Files** supported by Windows. More reference about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/stg/structured-storage-start-page

MSDN Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b5f6406-aef7-41a3-9560-bfe658f7d3c5/c-store-all-files-folders-in-a-windows-form?forum=winforms